# Conditional use of $ on summary field

Tags: crystal-reports

My summary field displays dollars. If the value is zero, I want to display a dash without the $ symbol. I currently have in the custom style settings to Show Zero Values as a "-", however, what I get in the report is "$-"

I see that there is a conditional formatting option, but I'm not sure how to refer to the summarized field in the code. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the given field, go to Format Editor, and select Custom Style. Then click `Customize...` and Enable Currency Symbol. Click the X+2 button and enter the following formula:

```
If {yourFieldName} >= 0 Then
    crFloatingCurrencySymbol
Else
    crNoCurrencySymbol
```

If you prefer a fixed currency symbol, you can use `crFixedCurrencySymbol` instead of `crFloatingCurrencySymbol`.

Comment: That's perfect.  The problem is, I don't know the field name because it's a summary field.

Comment: You'll need to replace `{yourFieldName}` with whatever appears when you double-click the field in the Formula Workshop. Same as before.

Comment: okay sorry, i'm a bit confused on that point. So right now, the field is called `Sum of CostTable.CurrentCost`.  Is that what replaces `{yourFieldName}`?

Comment: okay, it shows up as `Sum{{CostTable.CurrentCost], {CostTable.CostType})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125432/discussion-between-4444-and-jfrizz).